# Alternating printing two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

How do I make this code alternate printing `countA` then `countB` then `countA` then `countB` and so on? Right now, it prints all `countA` and then all `countB`:

```
System.out.println(name + ":");
System.out.print("[");
for (int a : countA) {
    System.out.print(a + "A-");
}
for (int b : countB) {
    System.out.print(b + "B, ");
}
System.out.print("]");
```

Comment: countA should have been a container but you have named it count which is a really mmisleading name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Two prints per iteration

First of all, you need one loop instead of two. Then you need some method of interleaving the sequence.

The easiest would be to just print elements from both arrays per iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countA.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(countA[i]);
    System.out.println(countB[i]);
}
```

---

### Int sequence

Another possibility would be to use a bigger loop interleaving the values. Therefore, use an `int` range that is the size of both arrays together.

Assume you have two arrays, both of size `3`. Then take a range from `0` to `5` and print items from the first array if your index is **even** and items of your second array if it is **odd**.

In order to recompute the position in the array you only need to divide by `2` (integer division):

```
0 -> 0 / 2 = 0 in first array
1 -> 1 / 2 = 0 in second array
2 -> 2 / 2 = 1 in first array
3 -> 3 / 2 = 1 in second array
4 -> 4 / 2 = 2 in first array
5 -> 5 / 2 = 2 in second array
```

The complete code would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countA.length * 2; i++) {
    int indexInArray = i / 2;

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        // Even, take from first
        System.out.println(countA[indexInArray]);
    } else {
        // Odd, take from second
        System.out.println(countB[indexInArray]);
    }
}
```

Obviously it gets a bit more tricky if both arrays are of **different length**. In that case you would only traverse to the doubled ranged of the smaller array and then iterate the last part of the bigger array later, without alternating.

---

### Iterator swaping

You can do the same by using `Iterator`s and swapping them:

```
Iterator<Integer> first = Arrays.asList(countA).iterator();
Iterator<Integer> second = Arrays.asList(countB).iterator();

Iterator<Integer> current = first;
Iterator<Integer> next = second;
while (current.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(current.next());

    // Swap
    Iterator<Integer> tmp = current;
    current = next;
    next = tmp;
}
```

With that method it is super easy to make the adjustment for different length arrays. You only need to add this to the end:

```
while (next.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(next.next());
}
```

As, the previous loop was aborted since `current` has no elements anymore. Since `next` might still have some we traverse its remaining elements.

The `Iterator` approach has the big advantage that it also works for classes that do not implement `RandomAccess` (fast index based access) and that it works for all `Iterable`, not only arrays. And a lot of classes are `Iterable`. The downside is that it can not work with primitives.

Comment: in you int sequence code you have assume countA as size in loop statement and as containerArray in loop body.. please fix that.

Comment: @ShivendraAgarwal Sorry but I don't get your comment. I indeed assume that both arrays are of the same length, and I did mention this. I also proposed a solution if that's not the case.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < countA * 2; i++)  // here countA is thought to be an integer i.e. sizeOf container.
.
.

System.out.println(countA[indexInArray]; //  here countA is used as an array/ container.

we need a change in variable name.

Comment: @ShivendraAgarwal Oh, yes. I forgot to do `countA.length`. Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a plain old loop:

```
System.out.println(name + ":");
System.out.print("[");

// assuming both arrays have the same length
for (int i = 0; i < countA.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(countA[i] + "A-");
    System.out.print(countB[i] + "B, ");
}

System.out.print("]");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of iterations of both the arrays are same, then try putting both the sysout statements in the same loop. Like below:

```
System.out.println(name + ":");
System.out.print("[");
for (int a : countA) {
    System.out.print(a + "A-");
    System.out.print(b + "B, ");
}
System.out.print("]");
```

and if the number of iterations are different, then you could use a nested loop. Like this:

```
    int count1=0;
    int count2=0;
    System.out.println(name + ":");
    System.out.print("[");
        for (int a : countA) {
            System.out.print(a + "A-");
             count1++;
            if(count1<=count2)
            {
            for(int b:countB)
             {
              System.out.print(b + "B, ");
              count2++;           
              }
           }
        }
        System.out.print("]");
```

This should probably resolve your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] countA = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,8};
int[] countB = new int[]{6,7,8,9,0};

for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(countA.length,countB.length); i++) {
    if(i < countA.length) System.out.println(countA[i]);
    if(i < countB.length) System.out.println(countB[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
1
6
2
7
3
8
4
9
5
0
8
```